# Geolocation in cordova

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I'm building a cordova app that uses geolocation.

I installed the `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="4.0.1" />` plugin, and use it in a way that seem to work syntaxicaly speaking:

```
  console.log('Geoloc queried')
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    console.log('Geoloc received', position)
  }, (err) => {
    console.warn('Could not get geoloc', err)
  }, {
    maximumAge: 10 * 60 * 1000, // 10 minutes
    timeout: 5 * 1000, // 5 seconds
    enableHighAccuracy: false,
  })
```

This code becomes executed on app **load**.

When I test it on the browser, I get the following warning:

> [Violation] Only request geolocation information in response to a user gesture.

But when building my app, I reckon the permission is asked during app installation isn't it? Do I still need to add it during a user gesture?

Ain't starting an app considered as a user gesture?

What are best practices for an app that relies extensively on geolocation?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both iOS and Android are moving from indicating the permissions during installation to requesting permission when the permission is 1st needed. So you need to request user permission when the user tries to turn on the geolocation features for the 1st time in the app.

The Apple guidelines indicate that permissions need to be requested only when it is needed, not ahead of time.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/app-architecture/requesting-permission/

Same with Android

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview